# Android Architecture - Why creating single implementation interfaces?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, architecture

I've been working as an Android developer for 3 years now and I've always wondered why create single implemented interfaces for an app architecture, something like this:

```
interface SomethingRemote {
   fun fetchSomething(): Single<SomethingEntity>
}
```

and then, the implementation:

```
class SomethingRemoteImpl(private val service: apiService): SomethingRemote {
   override fun fetchSomething() {
      // Does some logic with the service class to return the specified class defined in the interface
   }
}
```

I've been following the [Google's Sunflower repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower), from reading it to implementing it in my last couple of projects and implementing new features or making changes is a breeze following the Sunflower's repo architecture but, I've also worked in some other projects that does this interface <-> interfaceImpl stuff and also adding more classes to a layer:

- Entity
- ViewModel (not to be confused with Google ViewModel, this is just UI data mapped from a model class)
- Remote <-> RemoteImpl
- DataSource <-> DatsaSourceImpl
- Repository <-> RepositoryImpl

All this files and single-implemented interfaces makes adding new features or changing simple stuff such as modifying a JSON property value from an API request a very confusing task, again, I've seen a lot of projects doing this and I don't understand why do this when workin with the architecture exemplified in Sunflower is less confusing and it goes more "to the point", Im asking for the benefits of doing this single-implemented interface approach.

me, personally, [Im against the "Impl" suffix](https://octoperf.com/blog/2016/10/27/impl-classes-are-evil/).

Comment: Frequently, this comes back to testing. Mockito-style can get you quite a ways, but by using interfaces, your tests can create much more elaborate fake implementations for your tests to work against.

Comment: so, this comes more from a tesing-driven development? Using the recommendations from Sunflower also makes the code testable, quite testable tbh, without the cost of making the maining chore confusing, so, testability is the only benefit or there is more to it? and at what cost?

Comment: How is it confusing?

Comment: I would say there are few arguments: 1) some mocking and testing libraries can only mock interfaces, or have less functionality mocking classes 2) the promise of always be able to implement the interface differently, while keeping both implementations around. 3) An interface can be exposed without leaking implementation dependencies, even though there's only one implementation (think in terms of gradle module dependencies api vs implementation) 4) TDD or Clean architecture usually starts defining interfaces, implementations comes later on in the development process

Comment: @DaveNewton Imagine you have to add a simple endpoint that fetches a list of something, you have to create a lot of file for that, for this Ill asume the use of retrofit

- POJO/POKO for Retrofit
- Retrofit Interface
- DataSource Interface
- DataSourceImpl
- Repository Model Class
- Repository Interface
- Repository Impl
- RemoteMapperToRepositoryModelMapper
- UseCase
- UseCaseImpl
- ViewModel / Presenter
- UIModel
- RepositoryModelToUIModelMapper
- Fragment
- Activity

is really that necessary to write all this files when those interfaces are going to be implemented once?

Comment: @AlfredoBejarano *shrug* Creating an interface from an implementation is a click or few in the IDE, and it does the refactoring-to-interface for you. Even if it didn't, it's still pretty trivial. Refactoring to interfaces for the *sake* of refactoring to interfaces is silly, but that goes without saying.

Comment: @AlfredoBejarano Only your application can answer whether or not it's "really that necessary".